# How to change parameters on debian grub files

Tags: linux, debian

I recently changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT parameter from "quiet" to "nomodeset" in /etc/default/grub. After reboot Debian screen is black. How can i get entry to /etc/default/grub and release old options now?

Answer (score 0):

You need to update grub

try `sudo update-grub`

Comment: But main problem is that I cant even run terminal. I have only access to grub terminal and i can modify instructions before start-up. When i try to run Debian, screen is black.